# Why datatable adds more <td> to my table

Tags: java, jsf

this is my jsf:

```
 <h:dataTable class="pretty" value="#{ftController.ftDataModel}" var="item">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Amount"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column >
                        <f:facet class="right" name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Date"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>      
                        <h:outputLink   value="index.jsf"><h:outputText value="#{item.ftType}"/></h:outputLink><br />
                          <h:outputText class="red" id="amount"   value="#{item.amount}"></h:outputText> <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText  style="font-size:12px" class="gray" value="TL" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column class="right" >
                        <h:outputText id="date"    value="#{item.date}"></h:outputText> 
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
```

howerver, html output is just like that:

```
<table class="pretty">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">Amount</th>
<th scope="col">Date</th>
<th scope="col"></th>
<th scope="col"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="index.jsf" class="ui-link">Person</a><br><span id="j_idt8:j_idt21:0:amount" class="red">34500.6</span>&nbsp;<span class="gray" style="font-size:12px">TL</span></td>
<td><span id="j_idt8:j_idt21:0:date">10/14/2012</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="index.jsf" class="ui-link">Person</a><br><span id="j_idt8:j_idt21:1:amount" class="red">3444.78</span>&nbsp;<span class="gray" style="font-size:12px">TL</span></td>
<td><span id="j_idt8:j_idt21:1:date">10/15/2012</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It adds extra `<th>` for ex under the amount and date. And also it adds `<td>s` why? What is the problem here? How can i solve it? Why it adds?

Comment: What problem you are facing because of that?

Comment: Its just the HTNL source of your datatable. **`Column facet`== `HTML th`** and **`column`== `HTML td`**

Comment: This is the expected behavior. You defined 4 `<p:column>`. So it adds 4 `<td>` and 4 `<th>`.

Comment: Just be sure to check out how to use the header facet in a JSF datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest `<f:facet>` within `<h:column>` **together** with row data. What you telled JSF in your code is to create 4 columns, where the first two would have empty row data and defined header text and the following two would have everything reversed. Fix it like:

```
            <h:dataTable class="pretty" value="#{ftController.ftDataModel}" var="item">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Amount"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLink   value="index.jsf"><h:outputText value="#{item.ftType}"/></h:outputLink><br />
                      <h:outputText class="red" id="amount"   value="#{item.amount}"></h:outputText> <h:outputText value="&#160;" /><h:outputText  style="font-size:12px" class="gray" value="TL" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column >
                    <f:facet class="right" name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Date"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText id="date"    value="#{item.date}"></h:outputText> 
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have 4   `<h:column>`   in your data table. and 3rd and 4th have not **name** attribute so it's blank.